# How do you extend a vector to match another one by repeating its values in R?

Tags: r, data-science

I have one a sequence of numbers which contain different values (12912   13368   13412   13780   14725   15765   24791   23549   20821   42969 )

and I want to insert it into as a new column in a dataframe so that each value is repeated ten times... (12912   12912 12912 12912 12912 12912 12912 12912 12912 12912  13368  13368  13368  13368  13368  13368  13368  13368  13368  13368 ..., etc)

Comment: rep(v, each = 10), where v is your vector

Answer (score 0):

See ?rep for how that function works. `df` is your dataframe or matrix:

```
  vals <- c(12912, 13368, 13412, 13780, 14725, 15765, 24791, 23549, 20821, 42969 )
  newcol <- rep(vals, each = 10)
  df <- cbind(df, newcol)
```